# Unable to create extension attribute for billing address in Magento 2

Tags: checkout, custom-field, extension-attributes

I have added custom field in magento checkout billing form, to get the value for field, I have added extension attribute

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="billing_dob" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
```

but it is not generating get and set method and on click of place order showing below error

```
webapi-5c7e954226a41; Message: Property "BillingDob" does not have accessor method "getBillingDob" in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface".
```

Below is my mixin file :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setBillingAddressAction) {

        return wrapper.wrap(setBillingAddressAction, function (originalAction) {  
            var billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();
            billingAddress['billing_dob'] = $("[name='billing_dob']").val();
            if (billingAddress && billingAddress.customAttributes){
                if (billingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                    billingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
                }
                var taxcode = billingAddress.customAttributes['billing_dob'];
                if($.isPlainObject(taxcode)){
                    taxcode = taxcode['value'];
                }
                billingAddress['extension_attributes']['billing_dob'] = $("[name='billing_dob']").val();
            }
            return originalAction();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Now BillingDob() method generated but still same issue.

Comment: you need to compile after add extension attribute

Comment: @KetanBorada, I am compiling using:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: check in appropriate generated folder is it created or not?

Comment: @KetanBorada, yes this time created, but error is same on click of place order button

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue and fixed when I remove the line adding my custom addtribute code in two js address files (or your custom files in case you're overriding these core files in your custom module or custom theme):

```
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/new-customer-address'
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/customer/address'
```

....

```
return {
        customerAddressId: addressData.id,
        email: addressData.email,
        countryId: addressData['country_id'],
        regionId: regionId,
        regionCode: addressData.region['region_code'],
        region: addressData.region.region,
        customerId: addressData['customer_id'],
        street: addressData.street,
        company: addressData.company,
        telephone: addressData.telephone,
        fax: addressData.fax,
        postcode: addressData.postcode,
        city: addressData.city,

        //
        // remove this line
        //
        // customAttribute: addressData.customAttribute,
        //

        firstname: addressData.firstname,
        lastname: addressData.lastname,
        middlename: addressData.middlename,
        prefix: addressData.prefix,
        suffix: addressData.suffix,
        vatId: addressData['vat_id'],
        sameAsBilling: addressData['same_as_billing'],
        saveInAddressBook: addressData['save_in_address_book'],
        customAttributes: addressData['custom_attributes'],

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        isDefaultShipping: function () {
            return addressData['default_shipping'];
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        isDefaultBilling: function () {
            return addressData['default_billing'];
        },

        ....
    };
```

Hope this help!